For a symmetric matrix, why not column space and null space are orthogonal complement?
Since $A^T = A$ we have $N(A^T)=N(A)$ and $C(A^T)=C(A)$ then why not $C(A)^⊥=N(A)$ ?
Here's my question source:

solution


What is $L$? The statement in your question is correct.

Lker means Left kernel. I think the question statement is True. Right? C(A)=$N(A)^⊥$. I should answer True for this question.

Yes, that’s correct.
